# regex to match if string has ev or pp using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex to match a condition like below:

if ev or pp is in the begining of string and has any number after that,then it should match

For example:

if string is ev100 then it will satisify the condition so it should print ev100.

if string is pp44 then print pp44.

if string is ep39 then it will not satisfy the condition. Hence it should not be printed

Comment: _"Hence it should be printed"_: did you mean "Hence it should __not__ be printed"?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

You may use `match` here with the regex pattern `^(?:ev|pp)\d+`:

```js
var inputs = ["ev100", "pp44", "ep39"];
inputs.forEach(x => x.match(/^(?:ev|pp)\d+/) ? console.log(x) : "");
```

Comment: it won't be an array of string, either of the one string will be available at a time and is dynamic

Comment: @TechLearn I am only using an array to show that your positive cases pass while the negative ones fail.  You may adapt my answer however you see fit.